# CronJob command to delete multiple subdirectories by name in a given directory

Tags: find, cron, command, exec, delete

I have two IP cameras which are sending image snapshots to an FTP server every 10 seconds, from 08:00 to 20:59. The directory structure looks like this:

```
`-- public_html
    `-- securitycams
        |-- cam01
        |   |-- 20190601
        |   |   |-- 08
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_080000.jpg
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_080010.jpg
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_080020.jpg
        |   |   |   `-- ...
        |   |   |-- 09
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_090000.jpg
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_090010.jpg
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_090020.jpg
        |   |   |   `-- ...
        |   |   |-- 10
        |   |   |-- 11
        |   |   |-- 12
        |   |   |-- 13
        |   |   |-- 14
        |   |   |-- 15
        |   |   |-- 16
        |   |   |-- 17
        |   |   |-- 18
        |   |   |-- 19
        |   |   `-- 20
        |   `-- 20190602
        |       |-- 08
        |       |   |-- 20190602_080000.jpg
        |       |   |-- 20190602_080010.jpg
        |       |   |-- 20190602_080020.jpg
        |       |   `-- ...
        |       |-- 09
        |       |   |-- 20190602_090000.jpg
        |       |   |-- 20190602_090010.jpg
        |       |   |-- 20190602_090020.jpg
        |       |   `-- ...
        |       |-- 10
        |       |-- 11
        |       |-- 12
        |       |-- 13
        |       |-- 14
        |       |-- 15
        |       |-- 16
        |       |-- 17
        |       |-- 18
        |       |-- 19
        |       `-- 20
        `-- cam02
        |   |-- 20190601
        |   |   |-- 08
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_080000.jpg
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_080010.jpg
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_080020.jpg
        |   |   |   `-- ...
        |   |   |-- 09
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_090000.jpg
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_090010.jpg
        |   |   |   |-- 20190601_090020.jpg
        |   |   |   `-- ...
        |   |   |-- 10
        |   |   |-- 11
        |   |   |-- 12
        |   |   |-- 13
        |   |   |-- 14
        |   |   |-- 15
        |   |   |-- 16
        |   |   |-- 17
        |   |   |-- 18
        |   |   |-- 19
        |   |   `-- 20
        |   `-- 20190602
        |       |-- 08
        |       |   |-- 20190602_080000.jpg
        |       |   |-- 20190602_080010.jpg
        |       |   |-- 20190602_080020.jpg
        |       |   `-- ...
        |       |-- 09
        |       |   |-- 20190602_090000.jpg
        |       |   |-- 20190602_090010.jpg
        |       |   |-- 20190602_090020.jpg
        |       |   `-- ...
        |       |-- 10
        |       |-- 11
        |       |-- 12
        |       |-- 13
        |       |-- 14
        |       |-- 15
        |       |-- 16
        |       |-- 17
        |       |-- 18
        |       |-- 19
        |       `-- 20
```

I'm only interested in keeping a copy of the snapshots taken between:

```
08:00 and 09:59
13:00 and 14:59
19:00 and 20:59.
```

Therefore I would like to create a **CronJob** that will periodically delete all directories named "10", "11", "12", "15", "16", "17" and "18".

I'm a newbie in UNIX commands and searched a lot. I managed to create this command:

```
find /home/******/public_html/securitycams/* -depth \( -name "10" -or -name "11" -or -name "12" -or -name "15" -or -name "16" -or -name "17" -or -name "18" \) -type d -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

It seems to work. But is that the correct way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You command looks good to me. But you could shorten it a little bit:

- `-depth` can be removed
- `\( -name ... -or -name ... \)` can be shortened
- instead of `{} \;` you could use `{} +` resulting in only one invocation of `rm`

```
find /home/******/public_html/securitycams -type d -name "1[0-25-8]" -exec rm -r {} +
```

If your cameras can be configured to store images between 08:00 and 20:59, maybe they can  also be configured to only store images between 08:00 and 09:59, 13:00 and 14:59 and 19:00 and 20:59?

I think there is no "correct way" to do this. If a cron job works for you, why not?